# Youtube play only once in WebView

Tags: android, flash, webview, youtube

I have the following code. It successfully stream the video from YouTube. But when the video ended. It cannot be played again, not even if I quit and re-enter the app. It always shows the loading page then jump to suggested video immediately.

```
public class HdPlayer extends CustomView {
Button share_btn;
DisplaySize mDisplaySize;
String youtubeLink = null;
String thumbnailLink, description, VideoId, viewCount, date = null;
String title = null;
WebView webview;
String duration = null;

DbAdapter db;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Remove notification bar
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.hd_player);
    db = new DbAdapter(this);

    titlebar_title.setText("Playing");
    titlebar_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.titlebar_play);
    Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    youtubeLink = bundle.getString("youtubeLink");


    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view_player);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    // webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);// completely zoomed out
    // webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webview.getTouchables();

    webview.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000"));
    mDisplaySize = new DisplaySize(this);

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int[] widthHeight = new int[2];
    widthHeight = mDisplaySize.getDisplaySize(display);
    int width = widthHeight[0];
    int height = widthHeight[1];
    Log.i("iframe", " before iframe");
    String emdLink = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + VideoId;
    Log.i("iframe", " before loadData, youtubeLink: " + emdLink);

    LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width,
            (width / 4) * 3);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    webview.setLayoutParams(lp);
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webview.loadUrl(emdLink);


}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    try {
        Log.i("in onpause", "onpause try" );
        Class.forName("android.webkit.WebView")
                .getMethod("onPause", (Class[]) null)
                .invoke(webview, (Object[]) null);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException nsme) {
    } catch (InvocationTargetException ite) {
    } catch (IllegalAccessException iae) {
    }
    webview.clearCache(true);
    webview.clearHistory();
    webview.destroy();
}




}
```

It reports error: dequeueBuffer: SurfaceComposer::createGraphicBuffer failed

Comment: I think maybe it's the problem of hardware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works fine for me. Try to add this 
**webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());**

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){

});
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
webView.getTouchables();
webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000"));
String emdLink = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + "hPUGNCIozp0";
webView.loadUrl(emdLink);
```

Comment: @Lazy Ninja 
I am having problems to play youtube videos on api 3 amd higher api versions. Are you sure all api's webview support youtube videos?

Comment: @user1659006 what device are you testing on? By the way what is the class DisplaySize? YOu can use this to get the screen size Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;

Comment: @Amourreux, I am not really sure. I am testing on api level 13 and it works fine. Usually to play youtube videos, rtsp links are more suited for mobiles.

Comment: @Lazy Ninja 
I developed a app using "    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />" i have teseted my app on api level 10 ,13, 15 devices and the virtual devices. api level 10 having no problem plays youtube videos. but api level 13 ,15, 16 can't run. opens video but cant play. just black screen.

Comment: @Amourreux Ah Ok I see now! It is not only youtube videos, but all flash videos. Adding this android:hardwareAccelerated="true" inside application tag in your manifest file will do the trick. Had the same issue.

Comment: @Lazy Ninja 
:( can't add "android:hardwareAccelerated="true"" to application tag because of api level 8 has not property hardwareAccelerated android:minSdkVersion="8" . Thanks for help.

Comment: @Amourreux Mine is as follow     <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" /> but still can add it. Have you set targetSDK in your manifest file.

Comment: My manifest file     <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

  

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true">

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18212/discussion-between-amourreux-and-lazy-ninja)

Comment: @LazyNinja
i get this errıor Description Resource Path Location Type 
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'hardwareAccelerated' in package 'android' AndroidManifest.xml /...... line 28 Android AAPT Problem

http://postimage.org/image/r6unvvlcf/

Comment: @LazyNinja,Hey you there. Your code is not working in my case. Pls help